# Positioning some images inside a container taking into account image size and container size

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have a set of images that represent different parts of an animal. I have images for legs, heads, eyes, etc.

So, I need to compose the current animal based on its set of images. The main problem is that I want to resize/translate the images based on the container size and the size of the images themselves in order to always have the full composed animal in the middle of the screen maximizing screen coverage.

I have started with a very naive approximation that could work using a stack, and Positioned widgets and a LayoutBuilder, but I need the size of the images to calculate their position and resizing factor and haven't found anyway to do it:

```
class  AnimalBuilderPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnimalBuilderPage ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(child: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {

      double horizontalWidth = constraints.maxWidth/2.0;
      double verticalCenter= constraints.maxHeight/2.0;

      double bodyOffsetY, bodyOffsetX = "Here I need body image size to know how much I should resyze it and translated";
      double headOffsetY, headOffsetX = "Here I need body image size to know how much I should reisze it and translated"



      return Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(top: bodyOffsetY, left: bodyOffsetX, child: Image.asset('assets/images/body/b1.png',scale: 0.8)),
          Positioned(top: headOffsetY, left: headOffsetY, child: Image.asset('assets/images/heads/h1.png', scale:0.7)),
        ],
      );
    },));}}
```

Comment: try `CustomMultiChildLayout` - the docs say: *"CustomMultiChildLayout is appropriate when there are complex relationships between the size and positioning of multiple widgets"* - but actually i would use `CustomPaint` where you have the full control how and where you are drawing the images

Comment: Yes, initially I thought about CustomPaint too but wanted to give it a good with normal views. If not other answer suggest a better approach I will end using it.

Comment: *"[...] but wanted to give it a good with normal views"* - so first try `CustomMultiChildLayout`